# Resize bitmap inside a drawable layer-list not having effect

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I want to resize a bitmap in a `layer-list`, added as an `item`.

This is what I have tried,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <size
            android:width="46dp"
            android:height="46dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="11dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/facebook_f" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5, the preview shown is perfect but the actual image is a blunder.

Preview by AS,

[image]

Actual image,

[image]

Changing image resource size manually or in the xml itself does not change anything.

Note : 'f' shape image dimensions are 53 * 128.

**EDIT** : AS was using API version 23 to render layouts. When I changed it to 21 (on which I was testing it too), it appeared blurred. I checked the same on Android M device and the images were perfect. So now, this xml is behaving API specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:height` and `android:width` for `<item>` are only available for API 23 and above. If you use these attributes for API below 23, it will not give you an error, but simply ignore it.